# Composer not able to install private package that lives on remote repository

Tags: json, git, laravel, composer-php, gitlab

I've developed a Laravel package that I've pushed to my remote repository.
I've tested it locally with the following composer repositories:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "path"
        "url": relative/path/to/package
    }
],
"require": {
    "vendor/packagename": "v0.1.1"
}


"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs"
        "url": relative/path/to/gitrepo
    }
],
"require": {
    "vendor/packagename": "v0.1.1"
}
```

In such a scenario, when I run composer update, the package is properly installed in the vendor folder of my laravel project.

However, when I use the SSH url of my remote repository composer returns the following error:

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of
>   packages.
>
> Problem 1
>   - The requested package vendor/packagename could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

The strange part is that I ran my composer update with -vvv and at some point it returns:

> Importing tag v0.1.1 (0.1.1.0)

So why does composer return **problem 1** when it's clearly importing a tag with the right version number.

Here's part of the content of the composer.json that's in the root of my laravel project:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs"
        "url": git@xxxxx:vendor/packagename.git"
    }
],
"require": {
    "vendor/packagename": "v0.1.1"
}
```

Comment: Change type from vcs to git. Other than that yours looks identical to mine.

Comment: Tried it with both types, git and vcs. Same error comes back.

Comment: What happens if you change the version from "v0.1.1" to "dev-master"?

Comment: I merged my package into master, tagged it. After tthat, having "dev-master" or "v0.1.1" worked. It seems that composer didn't want to clone content that isn't in the master branch.

Comment: Yeah I've come up against that, it can be very picky about using the tagged source only.